# Valgrind gives incorrect line numbers

Tags: c, ubuntu, valgrind

I'm currently running Ubuntu Raring Ringtail x86. After a fresh install and updating, I installed Valgrind 3.8.1 according to the instructions from the "Learning C The Hard Way" tutorial. I can run Valgrind, however, instead of giving the line number of an error in the code, it'll just give me this:

```
==9300==    by 0x4060714: (below main) (libc-start.c:227)
```

*Full Valgrind report here: http://pastebin.com/1spmkFrU*

I'm sure I'm using the -g flag, and using *--track-origins=yes* will only show me where an incorrect function begins, not where the error is within the function. (This is the result of using *--track* : http://pastebin.com/ktvY8HEM)

Here's the makefile and code I'm trying to use:

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

EXECUTABLES=ex1 ex3 ex4

all: $(EXECUTABLES)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLES)
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*This program is purposefully broken */

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    int height;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n");
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Ubuntu 13"? There is no such thing. Use e.g. `lsb_release -r` to get correct release version.

Comment: There is, it's called "Raring Ringtail". http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: The pre-release images available are pre-alpha, and are not called 13.04 yet as it hasn't been released. It's just called Raring Ringtail. Besides, this problem has nothing to do with your distribution as you do something which is undefined. Undefined behavior can and **will** lead to weird ad bad stuff happening.

Comment: Alright, I can see how that would be a bit misleading.
I left height uninitialized and did not give the first printf a variable on purpose to try out Valgrind. However, unlike the response Valgrind should have given (pointing me to which lines errors are located at), it gives me a very inconclusive response, as I said in the main post.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined, which means what will happen can actually change between runs even. Undefined behaviour is unpredictable, so of course the response will be inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The stack allocation semantics for `main()` are kind of weird. Try putting the erroneous code in another function, call it from `main()`, and you'll likely get more meaningful results.

More importantly, try adding `-Wall` and `-O` to your `CFLAGS`. The unused variables and misuse of `printf()` can all be detected at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, at the same tutorials, on exercise 8. Even with the tracking enabled, Valgrind did not spot the line where the illegal address is accessed.

It seems that errors which are not fatal for the program but include accessing memory at illegal addresses, are not "pinned down" by Valgrind.
You can read more about these here:
[Excerpt from Valgrind documentation](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/messages.html)

I guess Valgrind won't save you from accessing the wrong places in your memory, so we have to be extra cautious.